# Inserting break inside span tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace @ with br tag inside span via jquery. But br is not inserting and whenever i insert there any other text that displays in result correctly.
I could not understand why br tag is not working and here is an example of my html code.

```
<span class="event-date-start">Oct 14 @ 1:00 pm</span>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
jQuery('.event-date-start').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).html(function(_, curr){
     return curr.replace('@', '<br />');
  });
});
```

I have also tried with .html but the result were same. I do not have any control over html and want to insert line break dynamically.
I ll need little guidance to complete this task.

Comment: Pasting your "jQuery" into a test fiddle worked perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/0xfus8zh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text()` will not insert html. Use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead

```
jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).text().replace('@', '<br />'));
```

Or as `html(function)`

```
jQuery(this).html(function(_, curr){
    return curr.replace('@', '<br />');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As i have mentioned in my question that i have already tried .html which is not working for me. Now i will try the second method.

Comment: Still not working for me. I am going to update my question to provide you little more detail. I have already tried this in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the text of the element and find each '@' and use replace, and then return the content of the `html`

Check out the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/juTtG/7/

HTML

```
<span class="event-date-start">Oct 14 @ 1:00 pm</span>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $eventDateStart = $(".event-date-start");
  var content = $eventDateStart.text().replace('@','<br>');
  $eventDateStart.html(content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a native JavaScript solution to your problem. You could probably translate this to jQuery pretty easily.

```js
var eventDateElements = document.getElementsByClassName('event-date-start');


function replaceWithBreak(element, stringToReplace) {
  var updatedText = element.innerHTML.replace('@', '<br />');
  element.innerHTML = updatedText;
}


replaceWithBreak(eventDateElements[0]);
```

```html
<span class="event-date-start">Oct 14 @ 1:00 pm</span>
```